# Bayesian Updating and Projection Theorem with Multi-Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, finance

I am interested in mathematical techniques frequently used in finance literature.

If $\tilde{x}$ and $\tilde{y}$ are jointly normally distributed, we can use the so-called projection theorem.

$E[\tilde{x}\mid \tilde{y} ] = E[\tilde{x}] + \frac{Cov(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})}{Var(\tilde{y})}(\tilde{y}-E(\tilde{y}))$

and

$Var[\tilde{x}\mid \tilde{y}] = Var(\tilde{x})-\frac{Cov^2(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})}{Var(\tilde{y})}$

I would like to know the projection theorem for multi-variables.

Let us assume the following:

$x\sim N(0,\sigma_{x}^{-1})$

$\alpha\sim N(\bar\alpha,\sigma_{\alpha}^{-1})$

$\beta\sim N(\bar\beta,\sigma_{\beta}^{-1})$

$\tilde{y}=\tilde{x}+\alpha$

$\tilde{z}=\tilde{x}+\beta$

Can we apply any useful formula in this case? If $\bar\alpha=0$ and $\bar\beta=0$, we can use the following formula.

$E[\tilde{x}\mid \tilde{y}, \tilde{z}] = \frac{\sigma_{\alpha}y+\sigma_{\beta}z}{\sigma_{x}+\sigma_{\alpha}+\sigma_{\beta}}$

$Var[\tilde{x}\mid \tilde{y}, \tilde{z}]=\frac{1}{\sigma_{x}+\sigma_{\alpha}+\sigma_{\beta}}$

How about the case when $\bar\alpha\neq0$ and $\bar\beta\neq0$? I appreciate any help.

Comment: You seem to assuming *jointly* normal rather than *individually* normal, which is a stronger assumption.  If so, then you should state it

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for pointing it out.